# QT Release build DLL procedure entry point error

Tags: qt, dll, build, release

I built an application in Qt Creator that does some image processing with CImg. It runs fine when I run it from the inside IDE, but if I try to launch it from its directory, it throws the following error.

```
The procedure entry point ??4QString@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0AAZ could not be located 
in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll
```

Everything points to having multiple version of the DLLs installed. I found my Xilinx IDE uses the Qt libraries, but the DLLs in question are the same version. I'm not really a software guy, and at a loss here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even if the library version is the same they may be non compatible. For instance they were compiled with different configurations, like with or without STL support, OpenGL, SQL drivers...

The simplest way to fix it should be to move Qt SDK's path at beginning of `PATH` environment variable. This way whenever you run an executable that requires Qt libraries it will load the ones shipped with SDK (the first ones found in `PATH`), unless there are already copies of QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll... in the executable's directory. For this reason if you redistribute your application you might also have to ship the libraries in its directory.

Another option is static linking, but you will be required to provide source code under the (L)GPL licence.

Comment: There are copies of QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll in the directory. That is all the application should need. Static linking is not working either. I'm about ready to just throw this back at the engineer and tell him to deal with the command line version.

Comment: @Matt Do you mean you put your QtCore4.dll in application's directory and still show that message? Probably it's the wrong DLL. Perhaps you took the DLL from QtCreator's directory, but you should take it from the SDK one, as they are _not_ the same (and your application is linked to the latter).

Comment: Ran Dependency Walker, and recopied the dlls into the directory. Not sure what dlls I used originally, but it works now.

Comment: Thanks, had CMake bin dir in my path and realized with "dependency walker" that my binary was loading those dlls, not the ones I had linked against.

Comment: Thanks, your advice helped me. Another tip is to use something like "whereis" or "which" (I have them in Cygwin) to check which Qt files are used. I never thought that the Anaconda's bin folder contains `windeployqt.exe`!!! Put Qt directory top in the Path. That should be in the actions check-list before reinstalling Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Static linking the libraries eliminates the problem.

Comment: But forces you to release under (L)GPL.

Answer (score 0):

Use DependencyWalker to list from where qtcore4.dll is loaded.
I had the same problem - DependencyWalker showed me that qtcore4.dll was loaded from c:\windows\system32 - but there was no qtcore4.dll in this folder.

Beware: On Windows 7 64 Bit c:\windows\SysWOW64 is "mapped" as c:\windows\system32.
And in this folder I found the dll - I renamed the dll and the problem was solved.

See this answer here:
[Qt fresh Gui application crashes on startup, faulting at QtCore4.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028362/qt-fresh-gui-application-crashes-on-startup-faulting-at-qtcore4-dll)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem [Windows 10, Qt5 + Mingw] and got the same error even AFTER I copied all the necessary Qt5 .dll files.

DependencyWalker crashed for me so I did trial and error method by copying files.

It turned out that I also needed libstdc++-6.dll copied too.

This signal that there might be additional libraries - beside the Qt ones -  you need to copy.