# Qt fresh Gui application crashes on startup, faulting at QtCore4.dll

Tags: qt, user-interface, crash, mingw

I'm relatively new to developing GUI aps in C++ and I have been having a few problems while getting started. So here's the story:

- I downloaded and compiled the QT libraries (v4.8.3) with MinGW 4.7.2 and configured qtcreator to use it.
- I can compile and run a plain non-qt console app just fine.

But when I try creating a new GUI application Windows 7 says  the exe created "has stopped working..."
Details:

```
  Fault Module Name:    QtCore4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.7.0.0
```

Now what bothers me is that it says the version is 4.7, but I am really intending to work with 4.8.3.
Now when I further investigated through the Event Viewer, the I noticed:
 `Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\QtCore4.dll`
But no such file exists on my system!

Furthermore, I found that my **app works when I copy the QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll (both v4.8.3)** to the 'release' folder that contains the exe.

So I'd really like to know how the mysterious older dll is appearing and messing things up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the [Windows 7 32-bit compatibility layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) in action. Files in `system32` are actually the 64-bit versions of various system files. You should find your mystery DLLs in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.