# QT Not including the correct library when running a build

Tags: windows, qt, dll

I'm building a program Using Qt Creator 5.2.1 (32 bit) with Mingw. One of the dependencies of this program is the libcurl library.

QT was building the file properly, however, when running, it would throw an error 139.

After running the dependency walker on the binary, I noticed that the libcurl dll in turn depends upon another dll called "libeay32.dll".

I did the following:

- Copied the my program along with all required libraries(including
  libeay32.dll) externally to Qt and ran it (this was successful).
- After that I tried running from within QT, but having the libeay32 library in the build before running (this was successful)

Logically, I presumed afterward, that if I put the path to the libeay32 prior to any other paths within my PATH variable, that It would pull the correct version of the lib (re: answer to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694140/qt-release-build-dll-procedure-entry-point-error)). However this did not work, throwing the same error 139 (it's apparently not finding the library)

I know I could run and test my program by simply copying the file into my working directory, however, for information purposes, I was wondering;

Is there any way of doing this without having to copy this DLL?

My instinct would have been that fixing the Path to point to this firstly would have helped as this would ensure that the DLL is pulled used before any other occurrences that may be there in other dirs.

Note: In referring to the PATH variable, I mean both the SYSTEM path and checking for the PATH Qt uses (Qt adds a few dirs to the path)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "Qt" doesn't add anything to the path, nor does "QT" build anything. Qt Creator does modify the PATH variable prior to building or running the project. You have control over such changes. qmake does the makefile generation. jom does the building. Please don't conflate Qt Creator, qmake, jom and Qt. They are, respectively, a stand-alone IDE, a makefile generator, a parallel make, and an application development framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you link static, or you have to ensure that your library is located in one of the following locations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications):

- The directory from which the application loaded.
- The current directory.
- The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
- The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
- The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
- The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.